# how to stop CountDownTimer in another Fragment?

Tags: kotlin, countdowntimer

I have three fragment, A -> B -> C. I started CountDownTimer in A fragment and want to stop it in C fragment. please help me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a ViewModel tied to the Activity of the Fragments (so shared between fragments), and start the CountDown there. Then in Fragment C you just need to get the same ViewModel and stop the CountDown from there. |

For example, by using `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0"` you can do in fragment A

```
private val viewModel: MyActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

and in onCreateView() call your method that starts the timer `viewModel.startCountDown()`

Then in Fragment C

```
private val viewModel: MyActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

and in onCreateView() call the method stopping it `viewModel.stopCountDown()`